# Python variable returns "0" regardless of input

Tags: python, python-2.7, variables, decimal

This is an excerpt from a fold equity calculator for no limit texas holdem poker.

The FDec variable returns a value of 0 regardless of the input to F. It should instead convert the percentage from the F input into a decimal.

Question: how to return the proper decimal value for FDec instead of 0?

```
print "X = 'Breakeven Folding Frequency'"

print "P = 'Current Size of the Pot'"
print "L = 'Maximum Loss'"
print "W = 'Maximum Gain'"
print "V = 'Villain Equity'"
print "H = 'Hero Equity'"
print "B.E. when 0 = XP + (1 - X)(-LV + WH)"

P = int(raw_input("Current pot size:"))
S = int(raw_input("Effective stack size:"))
F = int(raw_input("The percentage (%) chance your opponent folds to the shove:"))
print F

FDec = F / 100
print FDec

W = int(raw_input("The percentage (%) chance you win at showdown if your opponent calls the shove:"))
WR = W / 100

if (FR * P) + (1 - FDec) * ((WR * (P + S)) - ((1 - WR) * S)) > 0:
print "The shove is profitable."

if (FR * P) + (1 - FDec) * ((WR * (P + S)) - ((1 - WR) * S)) == 0:
print "The shove is breakeven."

if (FR * P) + (1 - FDec) * ((WR * (P + S)) - ((1 - WR) * S)) < 0:
print "The shove loses money on average."
```

Comment: There is no `return` here, and `F / 100 == 0` because `F` is an `int` smaller than `100`.

Comment: In python 2 division is always integer division so 80/100 == 0, 70/100 == 0, etc.. Try dividing by 100.00 to get float division. 80/100.00 == 0.8

Comment: @Mark_M: Or put `from __future__ import division` at the top of your file to get Py3 division, where `/` is "true" (float) division, and `//` is floor division (producing `int` when both operands are `int`).

Comment: Thanks Mark_M, 100.00 solved the problem. Had previously tried using float() but that did not work.

Answer (score -2):

In python / symbol returns the integer divisor. In order to get the decimal form you need to us // symbol.

Comment: Only in Python 2.

Comment: ..and only it both operands are integers.

Comment: Umm... `//` is always floor division, on both Py2 and Py3. If you want float results, you either ensure one operand is a `float`, or you add `from __future__ import division` to the top of your file so you get Py3 rules (`/` as true division with fractional component included, `//` as floor division without it).